# dayjs returning Invalid Date when using timeZone in Jest test

Tags: jestjs, dayjs

(Using dayjs v 1.10.7)

I have this file `date.js` containing a date function `isPrioritizedItemOverdue`:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
const utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc');

const timeZonePlugin = require('dayjs-ext/plugin/timeZone-custom');
const { populateTimeZones } = require('timezone-support/dist/lookup-convert');
const timeZoneData = require('./custom-data-2000-2032');
const LocalizedFormat = require('dayjs/plugin/localizedFormat');
const func = require('./func');

require('dayjs/locale/en-gb');
require('dayjs/locale/fr');

populateTimeZones(timeZoneData);

dayjs.extend(LocalizedFormat).extend(timeZonePlugin).extend(utc);

const isPrioritizedItemOverdue = ({ date, userTimezone }) => {
    if (date) {
        const todayInTimezone = dayjs().format({ timeZone: userTimezone });
        const startOfTodayInUtc = dayjs(
            `${todayInTimezone.substr(0, 10)}T00:00:00.000`)
            .utc()
            .toDate();
        const targetDateInUtc = dayjs(date).utc().toDate();
        return startOfTodayInUtc > targetDateInUtc;
    }
    return false;
};

module.exports = {
  isPrioritizedItemOverdue,
}
```

The `isPrioritizedItemOverdue` works fine in the application, but when running a test that uses it I get `Invalid Date` returned from `dayjs().format({ timeZone: userTimezone })`:

```
import date from '../date';

test('isPrioritizedItemOverdue', () => {
    const result = date.isPrioritizedItemOverdue({
        date: '2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
        userTimezone: 'Europe/London'
    });
    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with older node versions (Node 16 and older), with newer versions (at least Node 18) it works.

Node 18 came with some improvements to the `Intl` API (https://nodejs.org/de/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/#v8-10-1)